# Getting error text from @Dblookup?

Tags: xpages

How do I return the error text from an `@Dblookup`?  I have similar lookups that I suspect that are returning an error so I want to have a panel that displays when a lookup error occurs.

I have:

```
var dbpath = @DbLookup("","Setup","Setup","EIDBServerFilename");
var tmp = @DbLookup(dbpath,"FullName",@Name("[ABBREVIATE]" ,getComponent("inputTextEmpName").getValue()),"HRLogonID");
@If(@IsError(tmp),"Error= "  + @Text(tmp),"");
```

But I am just seeing "Error= " with no error text.

If I remove the `@Text` I get "Error = undefined".

How do I get the error message if it is an error?

I looked up both `@IsError` and `@Dblookup` in help but as usual the help is horrendous and does not even mention `@Dblookup` could return an error nor what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors from a @DbLookup in SSJS are internaly catched and will not returned.

This is because it is realized via *session.evaluate*, and if you make a bad @DbLookup in a *session.evaluate*, the full evalulation fails and you won't receive the error message of the @DbLookup.

In case of a bad @DbLookup, *null* is returned, and this is what you are testing with @IsError: *tmp* is *null*, this is why you get an *undefined* in your string.

If you make a @Text with a *undefined* value, an empty string is returned.

Hope this helps

Sven

**EDIT:**

If you run code in an evaluate statement you are able to get the error message. F.e. this

```
session.evaluate('lookup:=@DbLookup("";"";"X";"1";1);@if(@isError(lookup);@Text(lookup);lookup)')
```

would return the error message.

Comment: So who at IBM thought this would be a good idea?  How are you supposed to know why a dblookup failed?

Comment: I have added an idea how you can get the reason for failing.

Comment: Thanks.  Not exactly ideal but looks like it is a way to go.  I did something similar by translating the formula and putting it on a Notes form.   Kind of sad we need to resort to one of those ideas.   I still can't figure what the decision was behind not providing some kind of error message in JS @dblookup.